# Find type of elements contained in an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to know about some function (if any) or library which may provide direct functions to find the type of elements in an array.

Suppose I have an array containing elements of same data type :

```
var sameArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var diffArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 4];

sameArray.itemPrototype();  // Returns int
diffArray.itemPrototype();  // Returns undefined
```

For first array, it should return `int` and for the second one `undefined` or `false`.

Comment: what is `itemPrototype`?...Any custom function you wrote?

Comment: Its just a dummy name. I haven't made any implementation yet. And I will prefer using a in-built function in some existing library.

Comment: Ok..For first one, expected output should be `int`, but as second case have multiple types present, so expected output should be `undefined` as you mentioned..Right? If thats the case, you can simply write a custom function, probably using `typeof` inside it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arrays with primitives (like numbers, strings) you may use a simple method:

```
function getItemsType(arr) {
  var itemType, i;

  for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof itemType === 'undefined') {
      itemType = typeof arr[i];
    } else if (itemType !== typeof arr[i]) {
      return undefined;
    }
  }

  return itemType;
}
```

In this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/watodocobu/1/) you'll find a function implementation and integration into `Array.prototype`.